# ArcMap, equalize the value of xll corners and yll corners in two different rasters

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

I have DEM and landcover rasters, I have different values between my DEM and land cover map for xllcorner and yllcorner.
And how can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: Set environment extent, cell size and snap raster to any. Use raster calculator on second, no operation, or *1.

Comment: If the pixel sizes are identical, then all you need is to [Shift](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/shift.htm). Otherwise you drift into resampling.